# Object array needs to be cropped

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have Object array, and when I am trying to splice it, I get an error something like it is not a function. Any ideas why?

```
clients.splice(si, 1);          // => array => works
clients_list.splice(si, 1);     // => object array => doesn't work
```

Comment: array is a special kind of Object in Javascript that has a prototype function splice, so you van use it on that kind of object. As long as object is not an array, you don't have access to this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert array-like object to array in order to use array native methods. Use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method for this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(clients_list).splice(si, 1).
```

Or shorter:

```
[].slice.call(clients_list).splice(si, 1).
```